# MYSQL combine all messages to user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table 'messages' in my table where all the messages is being stored, with all the information necessary.

Here's a quick example with me as ID (23):

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    | id | to_id | from_id | message | answer | answered | anonymous |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 1  | 23    | 18      | msg     | ans    | 1        | 0         |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 2  | 23    | 2       | msg     | NULL   | 0        | 0         |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 3  | 18    | 23      | msg     | ans    | 1        | 1         |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 4  | 2     | 23      | msg     | NULL   | 0        | 1         |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 5  | 23    | 18      | msg     | NULL   | 0        | 1         |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*first row: I have received a message from userID (18) and have answered.*

*second row: I have received a message from userID (2) and not answered.*

*third row: I have sent a message to userID (18) with answer but as anonymous.*

*forth row: I have sent a message to userID (2) without answer and as anonymous.*

*fifth row: I have received a message but from an anonymous user.*

What I would like to group each user that I have sent or received message from and if a message is unanswered in with that user, give me 0.
And for each anonymous, don't group them as users. And show them one by one.

This is my code so far, but where to go next?

```
SELECT m.fuuid, m.tuuid, m.anonymous, m.answered, u.uuid, u.username
    FROM messages m, user u
    WHERE
    CASE
    WHEN m.fuuid = '$uuid' THEN m.tuuid = u.uuid
    WHEN m.tuuid = '$uuid' THEN m.fuuid = u.uuid
    END
    GROUP BY u.username
```

This won't give me each anonymous received message as single and the satus if the chat has an unaswered message.

From the table above this is what I want to get:

*id: 1 & 3 will be[user: 18, username: foo, answered: 1]*

*id: 2 & 4 will be[user: 2, username: bar, answered: 0]*

*id: 5 will be[user: 18, username: NULL, anonymous: 1, answered: 0]*

if id 5 is answered I won't see it.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please show the desired output based on the given sample data

Comment: Updated my question, hope it will shine more clearly what I want to accomplish. 
I wan't to group every message I have sent or received from a user into one. But if the user has sent me message as anonymous, it will be separate